# Setting up LaTeX in VS Code: error "Recipe terminated with fatal error: spawn latexmk ENOENT"

Tags: pdftex, latexmk, vscode

I know there are similar posts with the same error, but I have been trying to follow up with their solutions and somehow is not working. I am using windows 10, with Ubuntu and ​I downloaded Miktex and added to my $PATH. I usually use VScode for other work and tried setting it up for Latex with Latex Workshop, my settings.json file looks like:

```
{
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Abyss",
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
    "workbench.editorAssociations": {
        "*.ipynb": "jupyter.notebook.ipynb"
    },
    "latex-workshop.latex.search.rootFiles.include" : ["C:\\Users\\vscode-lecture-files\\**\\*.tex"],
    "latex-workshop.latex.autoBuild.run":"onFileChange",
    "latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
        {  
            "name": "latexmk",  
            "tools": [  
                "latexmk"  
            ],
            "includePath":[
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:/Users/AppData/MiKTeX/miktex/bin/x64/**"
            ]
              
        },  

        {
            "name": "pdflatex*2",
            "tools": [
                "pdflatex",
                "pdflatex"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "latex-workshop.latex.verbatimEnvs":[
        "verbatim",
        "lstlisting",
        "minted"
    ],
    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open"
}
```

However, every time I build my .tex file I get the error:

```
Recipe terminated with fatal error: spawn latexmk ENOENT.
```

I tried changing `latexmk` this using `Latex Workshop: Build With Recepie` and choosing `pdflatex`  instead and I still get the error:

```
Recipe terminated with fatal error: spawn pdflatex ENOENT.
```

What's the problem? Thanks for the help.

Comment: did you solve this? having the same problem

Comment: For me this was solved almost by itself. So after using ``source ~/.bashrc`` and reloading the VS window as well as restarting the computer it solved the problem. That's if you have set up your paths correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone found this question, maybe try rebooting your VSCode, and rebooting your computer first. It may sounds stupid, but such a simple solution works for me.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69984240/8598684